# What does "is or has been" mean?

Tags: tense, present-perfect

> Dating violence means violence committed by a person who **is or has been** in a social relationship of a romantic or intimate nature with the victim.

What does it mean by IS OR HAVE BEEN? Does it apply to someone who was and no longer is the boyfriend/girlfriend? If so, why not use "is or was"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**or** is used to connect two possibilities, for example

> Would you like tea **or** coffee?

In this context, it is considered to be dating violence if it it carried out by somebody who **either**

> is in a social relationship... - *the relationship is current*

**or**

> has been in a social relationship... - *the relationship is no longer current*

The difference between **was** and **has been** is that we use simple past **was** when talking about something that occurred in the past at a specified time, and we used **has been** when we are talking about something that occurred at an unspecified time in the past, but it is considered to have some lasting effect.

> The attacker was in a relationship at the time of the attack -*simple past*
> The attacker has been in a relationship -*present perfect*

In that second sentence, it is not specified when the attacker was in a relationship, but it is considered significant to the attack.